# insert error in Meteor.roles

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I'm using the meteor roles package for authrizations on my webpage. I have 2 roles defined, one is the `student` role and another is the `administrator` role. For all the new users registering on my webpage, I have assigned them the `students` role using the following helper:

```
Accounts.createUser({
  email:email,
  password:password,
profile:{                         //profile includes fullname and surname
    fullname:fullname,
    surname:surname
}
},
function(err){
  if(err){
  FlashMessages.sendError("There was an error");
 } else {
  FlashMessages.sendSuccess("Account Created");
  Roles.addUsersToRoles( Meteor.userId(), 'Students' );
  Router.go("/dashboard");
      }
  });
```

After trying to add a new user, the user does gets added to the meteor users collection and the roles get assigned as intented. But the console does returns the following error:

`insert failed: WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error index: meteor.roles.$name_1 dup key: { : \"Students\" }","op":{"name":"Students","_id":"w3vnwKrKJTNE8TpBS"}})`

Any fixes to that as I cant understand the error as the users get the roles assigned and are getting inserted into the meteor collection.

Comment: I think it's running twice. First time the insert succeeds. The second time around, it fails because the object is already present. Where have you put the above code?

Comment: @blueren The above code is a part of the registration form and is the helper of the corresponding template. As soon as the user is registered, i.e., `FlashMessages.sendSuccess("Account Created");` , I call the `Roles.addUsersToRoles` to assign a role to every new user.

Comment: @blueren Also, adding users to roles via `Roles.addUsersToRoles` updates the `Meteor user collection` to include a roles information to the users collection. Hence, I have included `Meteor.users.allow` rule on the server side helper.